# GroupBy condition with max amount needed to be added to Linq

Tags: c#, linq, grouping, linqpad

I have been able to get a grouping based on 2 columns , but I need to group by the 3rd condition when the Amount is not greater than amount specified

Here I built up test data

Results in Linqpad look like this:

```
Group PayFromBankAccountId PaymentType TotalAmounts  TotalCount
---------------------------------------------------------------
  3       ABC                5             600           3
  3       ABC                6             600           3
  2       DEF                5             300           2
  2       DEF                6             300           2
```

Problem is I don't want it to have any Group with a Number over 500 in TotalAmounts

Classes

```
public class PaymentGroups
{
    public Int32 Group {get; set;}
    public string PayFromBankAccountId { get; set; }
    public int PaymentType { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmounts { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentVouchers
{
    public string PayFromBankAccountId { get; set; }
    public int PaymentType { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPaymentAmount { get; set; }
}


var paymentVouchers = new List<PaymentVouchers>()
{
new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 5, TotalPaymentAmount = 100},
new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 5, TotalPaymentAmount = 200},
new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 5, TotalPaymentAmount = 300},
new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 6, TotalPaymentAmount = 100},
new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 6, TotalPaymentAmount = 200},
new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "ABC", PaymentType = 6, TotalPaymentAmount = 300},
new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 5, TotalPaymentAmount = 100},
new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 5, TotalPaymentAmount = 200},
new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 6, TotalPaymentAmount = 100},
new PaymentVouchers { PayFromBankAccountId = "DEF", PaymentType = 6, TotalPaymentAmount = 200},
};

var paymentGroups = new List<PaymentGroups>();

paymentGroups = paymentVouchers
.GroupBy(x => new { 
                    x.PayFromBankAccountId, 
                    x.PaymentType, 
                    // Sum of TotalPaymentAmount <= 500    Can this go here
        })
.Select(x => new PaymentGroups
{
    PayFromBankAccountId = x.Key.PayFromBankAccountId,
    PaymentType = x.Key.PaymentType,
    TotalAmounts = x.Sum(z => z.TotalPaymentAmount), 
    TotalCount = x.Count(),
    Group = x.Count() // unsure ??
}).ToList();

paymentGroups.Dump("final");
```

So I am wanting to have new groups  with the max counts of 500 , so maybe the Group column in final table needs to have group integer value to know  - Maybe this will also need to have some other ID as well ?

**What is it i'm trying to do?   Group by an additional column of a Sum of Amounts so that they can't exceed 500    thus in the linq code notice where i put "// Sum of TotalPaymentAmount <= 500    Can this go here"    Can that be done?**

Comment: You ask for "Another GroupBy" but it looks like what you really want is simply to filter the groups you already have? `.Where(e => e.TotalAmounts < 500)` (before your final `.ToList()`)

Comment: Could you include the desirable output of the specific input you gave as an example?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a filter instead, that filters based on Sum of TotalPaymentAmount in each group. For example,

```
paymentGroups = paymentVouchers
.GroupBy(x => new { 
                    x.PayFromBankAccountId, 
                    x.PaymentType, 
        })
.Where(x=>x.Sum(z=>z.TotalPaymentAmount) <=500) // Add Filtering here
.Select(x => new PaymentGroups
{
    PayFromBankAccountId = x.Key.PayFromBankAccountId,
    PaymentType = x.Key.PaymentType,
    TotalAmounts = x.Sum(z => z.TotalPaymentAmount), 
    TotalCount = x.Count(),
    Group = x.Count() 
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok , i see.   What if I still want to have this remaining ones show up in the results - but as long as they are under 500  .   So example of now this query returns only the BankAccounts for DEF  , thus 2 records  - and that is because they both total 300 ,   but what if i wanted the other records in there as well so  ABC  5   100   ,  then ABC  5 200  and ABC 5  300    -  ideally i want to group the 100 and 200 together , but the 300 will have to be by itself